# Nginx with static index.html and reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, openwrt

I'm trying to configure Nginx location for hours, not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name test.myserver.com;

    location = / {
        root /www/;
    }

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://192.168.0.170;
    }
}
```

Nginx is running on OpenWRT router, inside /www/ there is only a index.html file. All other addresses should be proxied to an Arduino in 192.168.0.170.

I understand "location **=** /" rule should precede "location /". I'm avoiding creating a rule for any other address than "/", like /a, /b, /c, and go on.
With this code, I get a 404 from "/", as there is no index.html in 192.168.0.170. If I remove "location / { proxy_pass ...}", I could get index.html result from "/" address.

EDIT:
-Including a `return 302 /blah;` inside "location **=** /" block works fine, so the rule is being applied.

Comment: What port are you serving in the 192.168.0.170 host?

Comment: @Danizavtz Port 80, with "location /" rule enabled I could access anything fine there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that drop here, the solution I've found:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name test.myserver.com;

    root /www/;

    location = / { }

    location /index.html { }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.170;
    }
}
```

Ugly, but it works. Maybe OpenWRT implementation (version 1.12.2) isn't as reliable a full distribution (current in 1.19.1 version).

Answer (score -1):

In my example, just copied you configuration and did a little tweak, to match with a current configuration I use in my server.

- Changed the listen to a `default_server`
- Added `root` to the server block.
- Added `index index.html index.htm;` line.

You can try the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /www;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name test.myserver.com;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://192.168.0.170;
    }
}
```

After change your configuration test your server block file with command:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

If everything is okay, restart the nginx instance:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

After restart with success if you are trying access via browser, try using incognito mode in a new browser instance. (just for cache clean)

Comment: Same 404 on index.html. I believe setting "index index.html" is default, so redundant.

Comment: How "/" doesn't fall in rule ```location / { proxy_pass ...}```?

Comment: It is in a server block. Not in a `location` rule